# .php requested URL not found on server

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404, c9.io

I'm attempting to create a webpage that allows a user to upload a file from their computer, and then POST it to my server. However, whenever I'm clicking on the "submit" button on my current webpage, it instantly returns

404 Not Found.
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Here's my HTML form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="myfile">
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Now">
</div>
```

Here's my folder structure, if I'm misunderstanding something.
 [image]

Sorry if this is a really obvious mistake, I'm very new to php

Comment: where is this current file and what is name this file?

Comment: Where is the HTML page containing the form in your folder structure?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my original link with my complete folder structure. For elaboration. my .html file is verify.html, and my php file is upload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a moron, I was running my website on flask which doesn't handle php.

Comment: hahaha I was worried about my problem but this made me laugh. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should put `upload.php` the directory where this current form file exists or you should provide absolute URL of the `upload.php` in form action.

Comment: Putting `upload.php` into the directory of verify.html returns the same error. How would I go about giving an **absolute** URL under my current folder structure?